# Múltiplas persistence units com Spring Data

Tags: java, jpa, spring, jpa-2.0, spring-data

**É possível criar várias persistences units conectando em bancos de dados distintos em uma mesma aplicação JPA usando Spring Data?** Por exemplo. Eu tenho uma aplicação que vai rodar em MySQL normalmente. No entanto, ela terá de fazer uma consulta em um banco de dados Oracle.

A primeiro momento eu pensei na seguinte solução:

1. Criar dois datasources no servidor de aplicação (um para cada banco);
2. Criar dois persistence units no `persistence.xml`;
3. Como estou usando o Spring Data, separa a criação dos `EntityManager`s e `TransactionsManager`s;
4. Separar os pacotes de DAOs que usarão os bancos distintos de forma ao Spring data saber qual `EntityManager`;

Bom, o problema começa quando no deploy, o WildFly acusa que eu não posso ter mais de uma unidade de persistência no arquivo `persistence.xml`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit definitions in application deployment deployment "authws.war".  Either change the application deployment to have only one persistence unit definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence unit.
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.ambiguousPUError(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findWithinDeployment(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:153)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.findPersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:75)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.PersistenceUnitSearch.resolvePersistenceUnitSupplier(PersistenceUnitSearch.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.getPersistenceUnit(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:372)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.getBindingSource(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:296)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.processMethod(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:206)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.processPersistenceAnnotations(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:143)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.JPAAnnotationProcessor.deploy(JPAAnnotationProcessor.java:100)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
... 5 more
```

O Eclipse também acusa *warning* em tempo de desenvolvimento:

```
Multiple persistence units defined - only the first persistence unit will be recognized
```

Agora um pouco de código. Abaixo segue o meu `persistence.xml`, com dois persistence units. Um apontando para o MySQL e outro apontando para o Oracle.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="authwsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/authwsds</jta-data-source>

        ..My MySQL mapping classes...

        <properties>
            <!-- MySQL -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/authwsEMF" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="antaresPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/antaresds</jta-data-source>

        ...My Oracle mapping classes...

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/antaresEMF" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E também eu alterei o arquivo `jboss-web.xml`. Veja como ficou:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
                               http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">

    <context-root>/authws</context-root>

    <persistence-context-ref id="autenticacaoCtx">
        <persistence-context-ref-name>auth_ws/authEMF</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>authwsPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>

    <persistence-context-ref id="antaresCtx">
        <persistence-context-ref-name>auth_ws/antaresEMF</persistence-context-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>antaresPU</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-context-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Meu ambiente de desenvolvimento para referência é esse:

- JDK 8;
- JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 4.3.7.Final;
- WildFly 8.2.0.Final;
- Spring Data 1.7.1.RELEASE

Eu achei alguns artigos mostrando como fazer isso justamente declarando mais de um persistence unit dentro do `persistence.xml`. Se isso viola alguma especificação, eu não sei ainda. Eu vi também muita coisa manual, ou seja, declarando os persistence unit, criando os Entity Managers na mão e obtendo os mesmo nos DAOs speradamente Como eu estou usando o Spring Data, isso fica inviável para mim.

Aqui tem [um artigo](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/hibernate-jpa/jpa-configuration/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-persistencexml) mostrando de declarando mais de um persistence unit dentro do `persistence.xml`. Aqui tem [outro artigo](http://blogs.isostech.com/enterprise-application-development/enterprise-application-development-using-multiple-entity-managers/) declarando dois persistence unit no `persistence.xml`.

Enfim, se alguém souber como fazer, eu agradeço. Meu próximo passo, que eu não tentei é usar dois `persistence.xml`. Se eu obter sucesso, eu volto aqui e atualizo a questão.

**UPDATE:**

Estou adicionando o código de como eu crio os EntityManagers. Não é exatamente o mesmo código dessa aplicação usada acima, mas é a mesma forma e ocorre o mesmo problema. No caso abaixo, estou tenho três persistence units (2 oracles e 1 MySQL).

```
<!-- Obtém a conexão do Persistence que é feito deploy no AS -->
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/poEMF" id="poEntityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.po.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="poEntityManagerFactory"  />

<!-- Antares -->
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/antaresEMF" id="antaresEntityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.antares.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="antaresEntityManagerFactory" />

<!-- Antares -->
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/e1EMF" id="e1EntityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.e1.dao" entity-manager-factory-ref="e1EntityManagerFactory" />

<!-- Especifica as configurações por anotações -->
<tx:jta-transaction-manager  />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

A partir daqui, quem toma conta das injeções dos EM em meus DAO's, é o Spring Data, que tem suporte a múltiplas unidades de persistências, segundo a documentação deles, mas eu não achei como fazer isso corretamente ainda.

Um exemplo de DAO:

```
@Repository
public interface PermissaoUsuarioDAO extends
        JpaRepository<PermissaoUsuario, Long> {

    List<PermissaoUsuario> findByUsuario(Usuario usuario);
    List<PermissaoUsuario> findByAtividade(Atividade atividade);
    PermissaoUsuario findByUsuarioAndAtividade(Usuario usuario,
            Atividade atividade);
}
```

Os JPQLs são gerados dinâmicamentes na chamadas desses métodos. Essa é a "mágica" do Spring Data.

Answer (score 4):

> (...) o problema começa quando no deploy, o WildFly acusa que eu não
>   posso ter mais de uma unidade de persistência no arquivo
>   persistence.xml.

Na verdade não é isso que a mensagem de erro acusa. Veja:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011470: Persistence
>   unitName was not specified and there are 2 persistence unit
>   definitions in application deployment deployment "authws.war".  Either
>   change the application deployment to have only one persistence unit
>   definition or specify the unitName for each reference to a persistence
>   unit.

Em poucas palavras, o erro diz: **se você tem mais de um *persistence unit* declarado no *persistence.xml*, então você tem que especificar qual persistence unit deseja cada vez que desejar acessar a base de dados.**

Você não mostrou o seu código que cria ou inteja o EntityManager. Se você por exemplo injeta o **EntityManager** assim:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Deve passar a injetar assim:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "nome_de_um_persistence_unit")
private EntityManager em;
```

#### Resumindo

Quando você tem mais de um ***persistence unit*** você deve indicar o nome de qual deles você quer usar cada vez que você injeta um **EntityManager** ou cria uma instância de um **EntityManagerFactory**.

Comment: Agora começou a ficar claro para mim. Mas a segunda parte da sua resposta não se aplica para mim, a parte do `@PersistenceContext` pois quem abstrai tudo isso para mim, é o Spring Data. Mas enfim, o que me interessa, é onde eu declaro o `unitName` (já que uso o Spring Data) para especificar qual eu quero usar. Pelo que eu entendi, é para especificar um unit padrão quando não houve um declarado, certo?

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Você pode atualizar sua pergunta com o código Java onde você obtém o EntityManager?

Comment: Irei atualizar. Não estou com o código aqui. Mas a noite, eu atualizo certinho.

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta com o XML que uso para criar os Entity Managers. Veja se consegue desvendar. Também coloquei um exemplo de DAO. Obrigado!

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti E onde você consome `PermissaoUsuarioDAO`? Imagino que você declare uma variável deste tipo e adicione uma anotação para indicar que deseja que seja injetada uma instância. Ou você referencia `permissaoUsuarioDAO` diretamente em uma página JSF?

Comment: Ela é consumida no Serviço, assim: `@Inject private PermissaoUsuarioDAO permissaoUsuarioDAO;` e depois pode usar. Mas não existe uma implementação dela.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, estou há dias procurando uma solução para esse problema de injeção de mais de uma Persistence Unit usando spring data.

Me deparei com a seguinte solução:

comentar

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">                                                                                                                              
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>                                                                                              
</subsystem>
```

no arquivo standalone.xml do servidor Windfly 8.2.0.Final e , como utilizo maven, a dependencia :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

estava como `<scope>provided</scope>`

removi essa parte.

Na configuração dos beans do spring eu fiz a seguinte modificação:

DE

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.rbs.repository"/>
```

PARA

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.rbs.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
```

utilizando os nomes dos beans do EntityManagerFactory que criei como

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"...
```

Hibernate 4.3.0.Final

Spring 4.1.6.Final

Spring Data Jpa 1.8.0.RELEASE

Por enquanto estou conseguindo utilizar as duas persistence units.
:D